# Eclipse Team Foundation Server plugin (Team Explorer Everywhere) giving null errors

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops

I have been using the TFS plugin for eclipse with my companies TFS server for several months.  Last week, my laptop crashed while eclipse was open and a connection to the TFS was present.  Now, every time I launch eclipse, I get an error stating a connection could not be made to the server, throwing a NullPointerException.

To try to fix this, I cleaned eclipse from my system and removed the installed plugin and then reinstalled eclipse and the TFS plugin.  Now, I am no longer getting this connection error on launch.  I added the original TFS to the list of servers in eclipse and it can see all of the projects (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLNQY.png).

However, trying to use any of the projects leads to a screen with an error message saying `Error querying workspaces: null`.  The error log shows the plugin in question as `com.microsot.tfs.client.common`, with the stack trace saying `An exception stack trace is not available`.

I am using the same exact plugin installation that I originally used.  I have no idea why I'm getting these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error logs may be helpful.  You can view them by going to Help > Team Explorer Everywhere Support, then clicking on the Logs tab.

Ultimately, though, this is probably some corrupt configuration files.  TEE performs some various background tasks and I suspect one of those was interrupted in the middle of some file I/O when your computer crashed.  Deleting the cache directory may be helpful:

```
~/.microsoft/Team Foundation
```

When you restart Eclipse, you should get a dialog box that indicates that your TFS server information cannot be located, but when you reconnect to that TFS server, your projects should return to being TFS managed.

Comment: Wow!  I searched everywhere for the actual TFS cache used in eclipse and could not find anything about it.  Deleting the cache directory is  exactly what I needed and has fixed my problem!  Thank you so much!